# Bootstrap angular ui modal template not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So I'm trying to show the modal template when a row is selected on the table.

The problem I am having is that when a row is clicked, a black shadowed line appears which is about 2px thick. It's supposed to be the modal I'm guessing but the modal isn't actually there in full with it's content.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Code for HTML Index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="containter">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>JSON to Table</h1>
            </div>
            <div ng-app="myTable" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
                <div id="table1Div" style="background:white;position absolute;">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="peopleTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Nickname</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="changeRowData(person)">
                            <td>
                                {{person.FirstName}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{person.LastName}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{person.Age}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{person.Nickname}}
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="centered">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addEntry()">Add New Entry</button>
                </div>
                <div id="searchFirstName">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Change Table Background Colour: </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id"buttonAndColours">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="tableBackgroundButton" style="float: right">Change</button>
                                <div class="colours" style="background-color:red;"></div>
                                <div class="colours" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
                                <div class="colours" style="background-color:lightBlue;"></div>
                                <div class="colours" style="background-color:green;"></div>
                                <div class="colours" style="background-color:white;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Search For First Name in Table:</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/> First Name being searched for: <u><b>{{searchText}}</u></b></p>
                            <br/>
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>First Names to be Searched For:</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:searchText">
                                    <td>{{ person.FirstName }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for Modal Template:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">   
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Row Data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" name="modalData">
                <form class="form-horizontal form-width" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstN" ng-bind="FirstName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastN" ng-bind="LastName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="age">Age:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ageN" ng-bind="Age">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="nickname">Nickname:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nickN" ng-bind="Nickname">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for Javascript file:

```
var myTable = angular.module('myTable', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myTable.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {

$http.get("xxxxxxxxx.json").success(function(response){
    $scope.people = response.People;
});

$scope.changeRowData = function(changeableData) {
    var modalTemplateInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
        controller: function($scope) {

        }
    });
}

});
```

Comment: angular.js is the standard angularjs file from the AngularJs website. (in reply to the person who asked about not including the angularjs file, deleted comment) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the solution alone. :)

Realised that the modal template means that some of the tags in the modal is not needed where they'd be needed when hard coding the modal into the html page.

Redited the modalTemplate file to:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Row Data</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" name="modalData">
    <form class="form-horizontal form-width" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstN" ng-bind="FirstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastN" ng-bind="LastName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="age">Age:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ageN" ng-bind="Age">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="nickname">Nickname:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nickN" ng-bind="Nickname">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser console output any errors (press f12 or right click and select "inspect element", and navigate to console).

Also in your browsers dev tools, open the network pane and make sure it's recording. Then when you trigger your modal, is it successfully loading your modal template file?

Comment: No errors and tried two different browsers, chrome and edge.
Also, tried putting index.html as the template url and that works and appears as a modal. But the actual modalTemplate.html is not showing up. :/ And yes, it does load the modal template file according to the dev tools. :)

Comment: Weird, well thanks for checking. I've got your code up and running and I see what you've described. It looks to be your template formatting, let me see if I can see anything

Comment: Nvm looks like you got it